# Concat several arrays in JavaScript (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

What would be the more concise way to concat all ar arrays in the following object:

```
var obj = {
  field1: {
    ar: [...]
  },
  field2: {
    ar: [...]
  },
  ...
  fieldN: {
    ar: [...]
  }
}
```

I found this:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(array, entry) {
  return array.concat(obj[entry].files);
}, []);
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with what you already have?

Comment: No, I'm just curious to know how this operation can be done with less characters.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
[].concat.apply([], [array1, array2, ...])
```